# How to keep session fb api graph to avoid (#4) Application request limit reached

Tags: php, api, facebook-graph-api

I have a problem with the Facebook API, **I try to test fairly regularly ids facebook pages liked by the user who uses my API.** But soon enough I got this message: **(# 4) Application request limit reached.** (in php)

Here's how I connect to the API and get pages:

```
$fb = new Facebook\Facebook([
  'app_id' => 'XXXXXXXXXXXX',
  'app_secret' => 'XXXXXXXXXX',
  'default_graph_version' => 'v3.1',
  ]);

$helper = $fb->getRedirectLoginHelper();

    $permissions = []; // optional

try {
    if (isset($_SESSION['facebook_access_token'])) {
        $accessToken = $_SESSION['facebook_access_token'];
    } else {
        $accessToken = $helper->getAccessToken();
    }
} catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookResponseException $e) {
    // When Graph returns an error
    echo 'Graph returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();

    exit;
} catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookSDKException $e) {
    // When validation fails or other local issues
    echo 'Facebook SDK returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
    exit;
 }

if (isset($accessToken)) {
    if (isset($_SESSION['facebook_access_token'])) {
        $fb->setDefaultAccessToken($_SESSION['facebook_access_token']);
    } else {
        // getting short-lived access token
        $_SESSION['facebook_access_token'] = (string) $accessToken;

        // OAuth 2.0 client handler
        $oAuth2Client = $fb->getOAuth2Client();

        // Exchanges a short-lived access token for a long-lived one
        $longLivedAccessToken = $oAuth2Client->getLongLivedAccessToken($_SESSION['facebook_access_token']);

        $_SESSION['facebook_access_token'] = (string) $longLivedAccessToken;

        // setting default access token to be used in script
        $fb->setDefaultAccessToken($_SESSION['facebook_access_token']);
    }

    // redirect the user back to the same page if it has "code" GET variable
    if (isset($_GET['code'])) {
        header('Location: ./');
    }

    // getting basic info about user
    try {
        $profile_request = $fb->get('/me?fields=name,first_name,last_name,email');
        $profile = $profile_request->getGraphNode()->asArray();
    } catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookResponseException $e) {
        // When Graph returns an error
        echo 'Graph returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
        session_destroy();
        // redirecting user back to app login page
        header("Location: ./");
        exit;
    } catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookSDKException $e) {
        // When validation fails or other local issues
        echo 'Facebook SDK returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
        exit;
    }

    // printing $profile array on the screen which holds the basic info about user
    print_r($profile);

    $res = $fb->get('/me/likes?limit=1000', $_SESSION['token']);
    $res = $res->getGraphEdge()->asArray();

    foreach($res as $page) {
        $pages[] = $page['id'];
    }
} else {
    // replace your website URL same as added in the developers.facebook.com/apps e.g. if you used http instead of https and you used non-www version or www version of your website then you must add the same here
    $loginUrl = $helper->getLoginUrl('http://localhost/index.php', $permissions);
    echo '<a href="' . $loginUrl . '">Log in with Facebook!</a>';
}
```

I'm looking for a way to keep the page consultation but every time after a while, 4/5 times I have the error message.

If not before it works. Do you have an idea to keep the $ fb object without necessarily making the call? In $ _SESSION it's the same thing.

Thanks

Comment: why would get that information on a regular basis, instead of just checking it out whenever he reaches your app? are you using a user token of that user? how often do you check?

Comment: You should not do this on every page load, but cache the result on your end.

Comment: In my site I propose to like pages. I have to check each popup closure if the page is liked then I perform an action. That's why I call every time.